# Arduino and RGB LEDs

Tags: arduino, switch-statement, rgb

Suppose I have an array:

```
int rgbcolors = {{R1,G1,B1},{R2,G2,B2},{R3,G3,B3},{Rn,Gn,Bn}}
```

How do I cycle through the values of this array by pressing **1 button** on the remote?
So pressing once, gives the first {R1,G1,B1}, pressing twice, gives {R2,G2,B2} etc...

My current void loop for predefined colors:

```
if (irrecv.decode(&results))
{
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  int k = 0;

  unsigned int val = results.value;
  irrecv.resume();

  switch(val) {
      case button1: //RED
        analogWrite(RedPin,255);
        analogWrite(GreenPin,0);
        analogWrite(BluePin,0);
        break;
      case button2: //GREEN
        analogWrite(RedPin,0);
        analogWrite(GreenPin,255);
        analogWrite(BluePin,0);
        break;
      case button3: //BLUE
        analogWrite(RedPin,0);
        analogWrite(GreenPin,0);
        analogWrite(BluePin,255);
        break;
      case button4: //YEL0
        analogWrite(RedPin,255);
        analogWrite(GreenPin,255);
        analogWrite(BluePin,0);
        break;
      case button5: //PURPLE
        analogWrite(RedPin,255);
        analogWrite(GreenPin,0);
        analogWrite(BluePin,255);
        break;
      case button6: //TURQUOISE
        analogWrite(RedPin,0);
        analogWrite(GreenPin,255);
        analogWrite(BluePin,255);
        break;
      case button7: //ORANGE
        analogWrite(RedPin,255);
        analogWrite(GreenPin,140);
        analogWrite(BluePin,0);
        break;
      case button8: //LIME !!! DON'T USE // CRASHES
        analogWrite(RedPin,133);
        analogWrite(GreenPin,255);
        analogWrite(BluePin,140);
        break;
      case button9: //PINK
        analogWrite(RedPin,50);
        analogWrite(GreenPin,50);
        analogWrite(BluePin,50);
        break;
      case buttonOn:
        analogWrite(RedPin,255);
        analogWrite(GreenPin,255);
        analogWrite(BluePin,255);
        break;
      case buttonOff:
        analogWrite(RedPin,0);
        analogWrite(GreenPin,0);
        analogWrite(BluePin,0);
        break;

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I unfortunately cannot help you with your "IR receiver value suddenly changed" issue, but I think I can help with your "cycle through the values of this array by pressing 1 button on the remote" question. The following is a code sample that does what I think you want to do:

```
const int NumberOfModes = 4;
int CurrentMode = -1;

void loop() {

    int rgbcolors[NumberOfModes][3] = {
        { 255,0,0 },  // RED
        { 0,255,0 },  // GREEN
        { 0,0,255 },  // BLUE
        { 255,255,0 } // YELLOW
    };

    if (irrecv.decode(&results))
    {
        unsigned int val = results.value;
        irrecv.resume();

        if (val == button1) {

            // Switch to new mode
            CurrentMode++;
            if (CurrentMode >= NumberOfModes)
            {
                CurrentMode = 0;
            }

            // Set output values
            analogWrite(RedPin, rgbcolors[CurrentMode][0]);
            analogWrite(GreenPin, rgbcolors[CurrentMode][1]);
            analogWrite(BluePin, rgbcolors[CurrentMode][2]);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Yeeesss, this works great, thanks! Still have my first problem though... the weird part is that in my 1st program it still works with the "old" decimal values while the receiver displays "new" values. But in the program I just ran above, I had to define the button with the new decimal value. Would it make a difference to use hexadecimal instead of decimal?

Comment: @Y.Terz asked "Would it make a difference to use hexadecimal instead of decimal?"

No, it should not. 

What are the two different decimal values you are seeing? How different are they?

Comment: From the same button: before 16738455 --> after 26775. So its missing like 3 digits. It's not a big problem now, because the value doesn't change anymore, but I was wondering why it suddenly changed and how to prevent it from changing again.

Comment: That's interesting. If you look at the values in HEX (0xFF6897 and 0x006897) it appears the first two "digits" are not significant. You could try masking the first two digits out and only comparing the last four digits (assuming they really are not significant).