# RGB LED strip - blue color not working right (with IR receiver/remote)

Tags: colors, arduino, rgb, infrared

So with the help of Matthew (thank you so much) in my last question, I managed to make my RGB strip work ... for every color except blue.

(Check here the previous question: [Arduino IR remote and RGB LEDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34021594/arduino-ir-remote-and-rgb-leds/34023170?noredirect=1#comment55890319_34023170) )

```
const int NumberOfModes = 10; //if you add a color, +1 here
int CurrentMode = -1;

int rgbcolors[NumberOfModes][9] = { //adding a color, +1 here
    { 255,255,255 }, // WHITE
    { 255,0,0 },  // RED
    { 0,255,0 },  // GREEN
    { 0,0,255 },  // BLUE
    { 255,255,0}, // YELLOW
    {128,0,0}, // LESS RED
    {0,128,0}, // LESS GREEN
    {0,0,X}, // Should be less blueish
    {128,128,0}, // LESS YELLOW
    {0,0,0} // OFF
};
```

So the problem is, my blue doesn't want to be less bright. It only works for X = 255. Everything lower than 255 causes some kind of error with the following outcome: the IR receiver/Arduino doesn't respond on other signals from the IR remote anymore (and I have to reset the Arduino manually).

Write to pin:

```
        analogWrite(RedPin, rgbcolors[CurrentMode][0]);
        analogWrite(GreenPin, rgbcolors[CurrentMode][1]);
        analogWrite(BluePin, rgbcolors[CurrentMode][2]);
```

And also doesn't mix with the other colors if X < 255; 
if X = 255 it does work and it does mix with other colors (R,G) that have values < 255

So is something broken in the strip/wiring or is something wrong with the coding?

**EDIT**

There is nothing wrong with the wiring, tested another program and the blue color works here fine. So it must be something wrong with the IR/Coding.

Comment: as far as I know, there's a seekrit hidden unwritten law that blue LEDs cannot ever be permitted to be run at less than "burn out your eyes" brightness...

Comment: The RGBs can have any value between 0 - 255 and it works great with another program (with an android app/bluetooth) but it seems to fail with the IR remote somehow.